# How setting permissions of magento?

Tags: permissions, file-permissions

I have some doubs for setting  the permissions of magento when the web site go to online

Always i setting file and directory 755.

It's correct?

thanks
Alessandro

Comment: version of your magento ?

Answer (score 0):

All folders permission should be 755 except var and media which should be 777.
All file permission should be 644 except files under var and media which should be 777

to give permission to magento run the following command through terminal.

```
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

sudo find media/ -type d -exec chmod 777 {} +
sudo find media/ -type f -exec chmod 777 {} +

sudo find var/ -type d -exec chmod 777 {} +
sudo find var/ -type f -exec chmod 777 {} +
```

Comment: 777 ??? It's very dangerous. no???

Comment: we have to give write permissions to media and var folders to which magento needs to write logs etc